In a html table using tablesorter, how can a row have a background color depending on the contents of one of its cells?
I am showing a HTML table using the jQuery Mottie tablesorter. I would like the rows with a "v" in one of its columns to be formatted with a certain (given) background color, which is retained after sorting the table. How can this be achieved?
    <table id="tablesorter_Table" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nw</th>
      <th>Atleet</th>
      <th>m/v</th>
      <th>Prestative</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Kees</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>274</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#e6ffee;">
      <td>*</td>
      <td>Sandra</td>
      <td>v</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

The background color is never shown. And I expect it would be incorrect after sorting anyway.

Is there maybe an event listener that calls, once the library has sorted the table?

Indeed, this is the https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/ .

You could try using the build in tablesorter events that can be found in the docs. Here I bound a sortStart and sortEnd event. Before recoloring, it resets the color of all rows. Once the table is sorted, it loops through all data. If one of the rows equals "v", it colors the row black.
$("#tablesorter_Table").tablesorter();
$("#tablesorter_Table")
        .on("sortStart",function(e, table) {
          console.log("Header clicked");
          $("#tablesorter_Table td").each(function(i, e) {
              $(e).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
          });
        })
        .on("sortEnd",function(e, table) {
          $("#tablesorter_Table td").each(function(i, e) {
               if($(e).text() == "v") {
                  $(e).parent().find("td").each(function(tdi, tde) {
                       $(tde).css("background-color", "#000000");
                  });
                  return;
               }
          });
        });


That is correct, thank you. I just copied the event snippets from the docs without looking at the bind function @fdomn-m

Unfortunately, the td elements have there own default background color that overrules that of the tr element. So, how to set all td elements then?Also, the "v" is in a fixed column, so not all cells in the row need to be inspected.

@JohanvanOoijen the updated code should do the trick, if not try removing the return; statement

I found the following to work. I had to add an event handler to tablesorter-initialized for the formatting before any sorting is done; the handler at sortStart is not necessary, because apparently the td formatting is already cleared by tablesorter. The procedure was made more efficient by testing only the td cells in the column with a header cell with text 'm/v'.
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )
  {
  // find the column with 'm/v' in the table header (th)
  var col;
  col= $("th:contains('m/v')").index() + 1; 
  // nth-child() is 1-based, while index() is 0-based
  
  // event handler to color rows with 'v' in column number 'col'
  function colorRow( i, e )
    {
    // check each td at position 'col'
    $('#tablesorter_Table td:nth-child(' + col.toString() + ')' ).each( function(i, e)
      {
      // if cell has text 'v', then color the entire row
      if ($(e).text() == 'v')
        $(e).parent().children().each( function(i, e)
          { $(e).css('background-color', '#e6ffee'); } );
      } );
    }

  if (col > 0) // column found!
    {
    // event handler for after initialisation of 'tablesorter'
    $('#tablesorter_Table').on( 'tablesorter-initialized', colorRow );
    // event handler for after sorting
    $('#tablesorter_Table').on( 'sortEnd', colorRow );
    }
  } );

